# Trying to fix my react class component. Getting the error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the error message:

> Line 4:2: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

I think I wrote this class component the same way I've written them in the past? Not sure what I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Person from './Components/Person'

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        people: [
            {name: 'David', age: '30'},
            {name: 'Michael', age: '27'},
            {name: 'John' , age: '33'}
        ],
        bool: true
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        const currentBool = this.state.bool
        this.setState({
            bool: !currentBool
        })
    }

    render () {
        let renderDiv = null
        if (this.state.bool) {
            renderDiv = (
                <div>
                    {this.state.people.map(person => {
                        return <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>show/hide</button>
                {renderDiv}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: A good start would be using semicolons.

Comment: i am implement project and not found problem.[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-wind-x02th?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code looks good. You'd see that linting error if you didn't have a `return` in the statement `return <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />` but since you already have it, it should be good.

[image]

But looking at the line number you provided, it doesn't look like that lint error is coming from this file. Could that be coming from your `Person` component? You haven't provided the code for it, so just an assumption.

Comment: Ohhh I forgot to add the return statement in my Person component. the thing I was trying to return was on line 4 in my Person component. Is that what line it was referencing? I don't fully understand the error message tbh. Also thanks for you help.